# How can I restore a single record from a MySQL backup file?

Tags: mysqldump, restore

Occasionally we have an issue where a record's previous data might get wiped while editing.

We backup our database every night for issues like this, however sometimes I am not available to do a restore immediately.

I've been asked to create a tool our editors can use to restore a record from a previous backup file.

I imagine this would look a lot like the a Webmin panel, which leads me to believe I may be reinventing the wheel. However, our editors find Webmin difficult to work with, so this isn't a solution for us.

Is anyone familiar with something we can use for the purpose of restoring a single record?

If not, are there any best practices I should abide by?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restore is overkill.

I'd use history/change tracking within the database/application itselF: then "rollback" becomes a standard day to day business or support actions

This would be with history tables, or [Slowly Changing Dimension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension#Type_2) type 2 tables, to store "old" versions of rows. Perhaps with some schedules clean-up to purge older versions

Comment: Thanks. So I would be able to use a trigger to track with the history table?

Comment: @Yazmin: yes, this is the easiest way